# Unicode Problem in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-office, unicode

Right now I've downloaded an excel project with .csv format, but when I open it[Excel Under Wine], texts are not normal, It's a screenshot of texts:

[image]

I think it's a unicode problem, How can I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use OpenOffice/LibreOffice?

Comment: They don't open this format fine, texts' position is not correct.

Comment: And that file works fine as CSV in Windows? It doesn't look much as CSV and I never had problems using CSV with OpenOffice. Which language is it? Maybe the wrong font? Which character encoding?

Comment: It works in Windows, It's persian[Farsi] and I dont think it's because wrong font, even if I Change it's font it wont get fixed. Don't know about it's encoding. but I know UTF-8 works fine with persian.

Comment: Ahh I finaly fixed it, Will add answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to fix it and that was it :

In Excel I went to Data Tab and selected ' From Text '.

Steps were like this:
1. Importing file with ' From Text ' Option.
[image]
2. Changing Unicode to UTF-8.
[image]
And...

[image]

[image]

It worked with CSV fine, Hope it helps.